# How to unregister specific "Registered PHP Streams"?

Tags: php, security

for security reasons I have disabled the function glob in the php.ini and it works as expected, but I also noticed that phpinfo reveals the following information:

Registered PHP Streams: php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, zip, compress.zlib, phar

So if I take following source:

```
$it = new DirectoryIterator("glob://C:\wamp\www\*");
foreach($it as $f) {    
    printf("%s: %.1FK\n", $f->getFilename(), $f->getSize()/1024);
}
```

It would still return the contents of the specified directory.

How can I globally unregister PHP Streams such as glob?

Comment: What is this for a "security reason"? I don't see any

Comment: Security in a sense of hardening. If it is not needed by the application, it is just another step to prevent an attackers from getting directory content information if e.g. they were able to upload an arbitrary file. Of course there are many other implications if somebody is able to upload arbitrary files, but this is not the question here.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: don't even bother trying.

PHP is a complete enough language that if someone is going to write dirty of vulnerable code, they can do it through any block you put in place. The only thing disabling functions like that does is make application developers' lives hell.

It's been proven that things like [`safe_mode`](http://blogs.ixiacom.com/ixia-blog/php-safe-mode-considered-harmful/) and [`open_basedir`](http://blog.php-security.org/archives/72-Open_basedir-confusion.html) don't *actually* secure anything. The reason is twofold:

1. Black lists (which is what safe_mode is) don't work. This has been proven over and over and over.
2. You can't secure on top of an insecure base. It's already too late. PHP itself already has enough access that even if you disable all the fun parts, people can still get around it.

Instead, protect from the bottom up. Install a `chroot` jail, and run PHP inside that. Use proper permissions. Vet the code that you run on your server. Monitor the server for intrusions. Nothing fancy. Just good old fashioned sys-admin work...

**To answer your original question**

The only way that you can unregister a stream wrapper is to do it yourself via `stream_wrapper_unregister()`. You could use an auto-prepend-file to do it for you (to run that code before every script).

But realize that it's trivial to implement glob in PHP. So there really isn't much point in disabling it...